# Call a function when a particular select option is chosen

Tags: jquery, html-select, onchange

I have two select menus requesting

1. a resident's building number and
2. their apartment number

If the visitor chooses the last item of either menu (both have the same `value,` `text` and `class`), I want to call a function that hides the form from them and displays a message.

The function is working fine as it's also invoked via a standalone link that a non-resident would potentially click: *(Don't live here?)*

What I can't make work is having the `select`'s `change()` event call the function if and when that last option is selected.

Here's a brief version of my select code:

```
<form id="document-request" name="document-request" class="clearfix">
    <label>Your Full Name:
        <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" class="span12"
        required>
    </label>
    <label>Your Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="span12 email"
        required>
    </label>
    <label for="building">Your Bldg &amp; Apt#:</label>
    <select name="building" class="span2" required>
        <optgroup label="Building">
            <option value="" name="building">--</option>
            <option value="1" name="building">1</option>
            <option value="2" name="building">2</option>
            <option value="3" name="building">3</option>
            <option value="4" name="building">4</option>
            <option value="5" name="building">5</option>
            <option value="6" name="building">6</option>
            <option value="7" name="building">7</option>
        </optgroup>
        <option value="nonresident" name="building" class="dontlivehere">I Don’t Live Here</option>
    </select>
```

and here's the jQuery:

```
$('#document-request select').change(function () {
    var theValue = $(this).child('option:selected').text();
    if ((theValue).contains('Live Here')) {
        residenceAlert();
    }
});
```

I have also tried to accomplish this by acting on the `value` as well as the `class`.
I don't really need that `dontlivehere` class, it's just part of me trying to find a solution.

The sample page-in-progress can be found [**here**](http://northqueensviewhomes.com/policies.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.child()` is not a valid jQuery function, try `.find()`

```
var theValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

I would probabaly just use something like this:

```
if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() === 'nonresident') {
    residenceAlert();
}
```

Comment: Spoke too soon in accepting the previous answer. Testing for val() (which is where I started my code initially but couldn't get to work) did the trick. Now only selecting "I don't live here." triggers the function, and all is well. Now to the next problem...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The browser debugger console will show you the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'child'
```

`child()` is not a jQuery method.

Change that to [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for example.

After replacing `child()` with `find()`, the next error you can get, depending on your browser is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'contains'
```

[**string.contains()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) is only supported by FireFox, using [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead might be better, unless off course you don't need to support any other browser.

Your complete code could look similar to:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var theValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    if (theValue.indexOf('Live Here')) {
        residenceAlert();
    }
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WccXM/) - Using `.find()` and `indexOf()`

---

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon. This code triggers the function no matter what I choose from the menu. @rusty jeans' answer did the trick.

Comment: @dashard: No worries. Using the sample HTML you provided and fixing your existing code the code works as expected as seen in the DEMO. Off course if that is not what you actually needed than that is a different story. Main thing is you got it sorted, glad you did :) Also `indexOf` is not jQuery but standard JavaScript and returns an integer representing the position in the `theValue` string the specified `Live Here` value was found at. If nothing is found -1 is returned instead.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line:

```
if ((theValue).contains('Live Here')) {
```

say:

```
if ((theValue).contains("I Don't Live Here")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

**HTML**:

```
<select id="building" name="building" class="span2" required>
    <optgroup label="Building">
    <option value="" name="building">--</option>
    <option value="1" name="building">1</option>
    <option value="2" name="building">2</option>
    <option value="3" name="building">3</option>
    <option value="4" name="building">4</option>
    <option value="5" name="building">5</option>
    <option value="6" name="building">6</option>
    <option value="7" name="building">7</option>
    </optgroup>  
    <option value="nonresident" name="building" class="dontlivehere">I Don’t Live Here</option>
  </select>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select#building').change(function() {
      var theValue = $('option:selected').text();
        console.log(theValue);
      if ((theValue).contains('Live Here')) {
      alert("it works!");
   }
});
});
```

Comment: How did you get around the issue of `Object has no method 'contains'`? Your code in a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ2DD/)

Comment: the fiddle you linked [**http://jsfiddle.net/vMAPn/**](http://jsfiddle.net/vMAPn/) doesn't work. It doesn't even reference jQuery. Please use the Browser developer console (F12) most of the time by default in Chrome and IE to check the error messages when using the code.

Comment: You are right, but with linked Jquery (select in left panel) it works. I use firebug to check errors.

Comment: I see, you are using FireFox. [**string.contains**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) is not supported in any browser except FireFox, that's why it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues:

1) child method.

2) contains method.

```
var theValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
if( theValue.indexOf('Dont Live Here') >= 0){
    residenceAlert()
}
```